# How to allow C# Web API to only accept plain-text Put request?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Why does my action method allow JavaScript to Put?

It lets through alert('hello');, but I only want to allow plain text.

I am using System.Web.Http ApiController.

```
  public class AppController : ApiBaseController
{
    public AppController(IReadyToWorkProcessor processor) : base(processor) { }

    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult Put(Guid readyToWorkGuid, [FromBody] PersonalDetailsVW newPersonalDetails)
    {

       newPersonalDetails.ReadyToWorkGuid = readyToWorkGuid.ToString();

        int? TeacherID = Processor.GetTeacherIdFromReadyToWorkGuid(readyToWorkGuid);

        if (TeacherID != null)
        {
            Processor.PersonalDetailsService.ProcessPersonalDetails(newPersonalDetails, ModelState, (int)TeacherID);

            ResponseMessage response = new ResponseMessage();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                response.Result = true;
                response.Message = "Section Completed";
                response.SectionComplete = true;
                return Ok(response);
            }
            else
            {
                string errorList = UtilityHelpers.ModelStateErrors(ModelState);
                response.Result = true;
                response.SectionComplete = false;
                response.Message = "Saved .... Section not completed yet, the following have not filled correctly: " + errorList;
                return Ok(response);
            }

        }
        return NotFound();

    }
}
```